# WPF Context Menu Binding Properties of Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I am creating a run-time document designer, for which I need show certain properties of the selected control displayed on a canvas. So if i right-click on a label, i need to show font-family, font-size.

I wanted to do this through binding, and I am certain this is how its done, but can't seem to get the code to work (it does not provide an error, but it doesn't work either. leading me to think there is something wrong with my binding.) please take a look...

```
TextBlock _source = (TextBlock)sender;
            _source.Name = "txtSource";

            ContextMenu contxt = new ContextMenu();
            contxt.IsOpen = true;

            //Font Size Menu Header
            MenuItem menuSizeLabel = new MenuItem();
            menuSizeLabel.Header = "Font Size";
            menuSizeLabel.IsEnabled = false;
            contxt.Items.Add(menuSizeLabel);
            //Font Size Menu Item
            MenuItem menuSize = new MenuItem();
            TextBox tbxSize = new TextBox();
            Binding FontSizeBinding = new Binding("FontSize");
            FontSizeBinding.Source = _source;
            FontSizeBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            FontSizeBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            tbxSize.SetBinding(TextBox.FontSizeProperty, FontSizeBinding);
            menuSize.Header = tbxSize;
            contxt.Items.Add(menuSize);

            //Font Size Menu Header
            MenuItem menuFontLabel = new MenuItem();
            menuFontLabel.Header = "Font Family";
            menuFontLabel.IsEnabled = false;
            contxt.Items.Add(menuFontLabel);
            //Font Menu Item
            MenuItem menuFont = new MenuItem();
            ComboBox cbxFont = new ComboBox();
            foreach (FontFamily font in Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.OrderBy(i => i.ToString()))
            {
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Content = font;
                lbl.FontFamily = font;
                cbxFont.Items.Add(lbl);
            }
            Binding FontBinding = new Binding("FontFamily");
            FontBinding.Source = _source;
            FontBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            FontBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            tbxSize.SetBinding(ComboBox.FontFamilyProperty, FontBinding);
            menuFont.Header = cbxFont;
            contxt.Items.Add(menuFont);
        }
```

Everything works fine, except when I right-click i would like to see the Size Textbox to show the current font value (it shows blank). Then when i update its value, we need to change the font size of the selected control (textblock).

same with fonts. what am I doing wrong??

Comment: So winforms, such bad, much dismay..

Comment: I down voted because you haven't taken advantage of WPF nor are you using it in a way it is intended to be used.  I suggest learning differences between WPF and WinForms, learning XAML, and learning MVVM.  Doing so will make your life a hell of a lot easier.

Comment: And not make the rest of us bleed our eyes out while trying to read that and see what's wrong!

Comment: You are learning and you get downvoted...SO is so nice. I recommend that you bind the information to a `ViewModel` in the Xaml instead of code behind.

Comment: i am learning, mvvm is really complicated, once i get a decent hold of wpf, mvvm should be pretty straight forward, but for now i have a simple question. sometimes feel I shouldn't even ask questions on stack overflow, because of righteous programmers that prefer critiquing a coding style, rather than helping with some basic problem i am having.

Comment: there's a reason people do not do what you're doing. But hey, it's your choice; feel free to code everything in a .cs file. Patterns are overrated anyway. Also if you feel mvvm is complicated, you may want to look at a different technology because that's the easiest thing in wpf world (though I'm not implying it's not hard to get hang of, but it's always better to get the hang sooner rather than later especially with bindings). If you had done that in xaml, it'd be 5-6 lines of clean code.

Comment: Also: given your specific problem, you don't even need mvvm - it can be done in pure xaml with an ElementName based binding

Comment: thanks maverik. i am a wpf newbie, and i got a hang of bindings in xaml, but since this is dynamically created, this is the first time i am binding in code behind. also mvvm i find it to be very out there, and all examples i find online are extremely basic so i have trouble viewing the big picture. anyways, i am working on learning mvvm, but it will take time. and yes, this is very winform-ish, i agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do not worry, I began to make code like this when I began XAML about in 2007 but I really like to make this question. Here is your answer

```
//Text
        MenuItem menuText = new MenuItem();
        menuText.IsEnabled = false;
        var textBinding = new Binding();
        textBinding.Source = sender;
        textBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("Text");
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(menuText, MenuItem.HeaderProperty, textBinding);
        contxt.Items.Add(menuText);

        //Font Size Menu Header
        MenuItem menuSizeLabel = new MenuItem();
        menuSizeLabel.Header = "Font Size";
        menuSizeLabel.IsEnabled = false;
        contxt.Items.Add(menuSizeLabel);

        //Font Size Menu Item
        TextBox tbxSize = new TextBox();
        Binding FontSizeBinding = new Binding();
        FontSizeBinding.Source = sender;
        FontSizeBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("FontSize");
        FontSizeBinding.Converter = new DoubleStringConverter();
        FontSizeBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        FontSizeBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(tbxSize, TextBox.TextProperty, FontSizeBinding);
        contxt.Items.Add(tbxSize);

        //Font Size Menu Header
        MenuItem menuFontLabel = new MenuItem();
        menuFontLabel.Header = "Font Family";
        menuFontLabel.IsEnabled = false;
        contxt.Items.Add(menuFontLabel);

        //Font Menu Item
        ComboBox cbxFont = new ComboBox();
        cbxFont.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<FontFamily>(Fonts.SystemFontFamilies.OrderBy(i => i.ToString()));
        Binding FontBinding = new Binding("FontFamily");
        FontBinding.Source = sender;
        FontBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        FontBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(cbxFont, ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty, FontBinding);
        contxt.Items.Add(cbxFont);
```

And as a gift the converter

```
 public class DoubleStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            try
            {
               return double.Parse(value.ToString());
            }
            catch
            {
                return 12.0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Try by yourself, I really like it,

Comment: thanks. i will check the code and give you the corresponding accolades.

Comment: works! thanks for the help. i realised where i went wrong with the binding.